# How to replace standard wcf help page with a custom one?

Tags: wcf

I have created a wcf service (.net 3.5, it uses wsHttpBinding and hosts on IIS), and when i'm trying to hit the service from the browser i see standard help page 'you have created a service'. I don't want to see it. Instead of it i would like to see some custom page.
I tried to use httpHelpPageUrl property, but with no luck. It just doesn't show the specified url.

This is a part of web.config:

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" httpHelpPageEnabled="false" httpsHelpPageEnabled="false"/>
```

How could i replace this standard service help page with a custom one?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229579/how-can-i-change-an-html-output-of-wcf-service-with-my-own-content

Answer (score 2):

Create a static page called `default.htm` (or a web form called `default.aspx`) in the same virtual directory as the service, and make sure it's configured to be the default page. I know it's not quite what you are looking for, but it would be just as useful to the consumers of your service.

Comment: yeah, probably it could be a solution. I made wcf service hidden and created a small app that touches wcf and executes simple method (smth like Echo) and then returns result: wcf works or not.